# How to introduce a OpenCV contour in a contour graph of Matplotlib?

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib

I'm working on a fluid mechanics project. Our goal is to calculate the velocity and pressure fields around a submarine profile (2 dimension).

I've computed the velocity field with no submarine and I also got the contour of the submarine using OpenCV.
I pretend to add the OpenCV contour to my Matplotlib graph and to calculate the streamfunction (velocity field with the contour inside the graph.
Is this  possible?
Would appreciatte any kind of help though I'm really lost.+

This is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

imagen =cv2.imread('Submarino.png')
gauss = cv2.GaussianBlur(imagen,(5,5),0)
canny = cv2.Canny(gauss, 10, 150)
(_, contornos, _) = cv2.findContours(canny.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cv2.drawContours(imagen, contornos, -1, (0, 0, 255), 2)
plt.imshow(imagen)



V=10.0
po=101325.0
To=25
d=1025.0
X=150.0
Y=150.0
n=150
m=150

dx=X/n
dy=Y/m
D=2*((dx**2)+(dy**2))
yy=np.arange(0,Y+dy,dy) #position at y
xx=np.arange(0,X+dx,dx) #position at x
v = np.zeros((n+1,m+1))
p=np.zeros((n+1,m+1))
u = np.zeros((n+1,m+1))

u[0,:]=V ##
u[:,0]=V ##
u[m,:]=V ##
u[:,n]=V ##
v[0,:]=0
v[:,0]=0
v[:,m]=0
v[n,:]=0

p[:,0]=po
p[0,:]=po
p[:,m]=po
p[n,:]=po

streamf= np.zeros((n+1,m+1))
streamf[0,:]= 0
streamf[:, m] = V*yy
streamf[:, 0] = V*yy
streamf[n, :] = V*Y


c=0
while (c<=100):
    j=0
    while (j<m):
        i=0
        while (i<n):
            streamf[i, j] = ((dx ** 2) * (streamf[i, j + 1] + streamf[i, j - 1]) + (dy ** 2) * (streamf[i + 1, j] + streamf[i - 1, j])) / D
            i+=1
        j+=1
    c+=1
i=1
while (i<n):
    j=1
    while (j<m):
        u[i,j]=(streamf[i,j+1]-streamf[i,j-1])/dx
        v[i,j]=(streamf[i+1,j]-streamf[i-1,j])/dy
        p[i,j] = po+(d/ 2)*((V ** 2)-((u[i, j]**2)+(v[i, j]**2)))  # from Bernoulli equation
        j=j+1
    i=i+1
#print streamf


plt.figure(1)
cv2.drawContours(imagen, contornos, -1, (0, 0, 255), 2)
plot = plt.contourf(xx, yy, streamf, 20, origin='lower')
plt.title('Velocity field')
plt.xlabel('X axis')
plt.colorbar(plot)

plt.figure(2)
plot = plt.contourf(xx, yy, p, 20, origin='lower')
plt.xlabel('X axis')
plt.ylabel('Y axis')
plt.title('Pressure field')
plt.colorbar(plot)

plt.show()
```